# How to recode continuous age in age categories and create a new variable at the same time

Tags: r, recode

I have an age variable and i need to recode it into categories.  I've see both of these questions asked, but the answers only seem to create something in memory.  When i open the data.table, the new categorical variable is not there.  I can't see it and i can't subset with it.  But i can run a frequency on it.  But i need it to be its own variable.

[R code to categorize age into group/ bins/ breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979456/r-code-to-categorize-age-into-group-bins-breaks)

[Convert Age variable into ordinal variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42166930/convert-age-variable-into-ordinal-variable)

How do i convert a continuous variable into a factor and have a tangible variable afterwards?
Or, how do i take whatever is being created in memory, and make it real?

```
`setDT(LSSCM)[client_age <17, agegroup := "0-17"]`
`LSSCM[client_age >=18 & client_age <=24, agegroup := "18-24"]`
`LSSCM[client_age >=25 & client_age <=30, agegroup := "25-30"]`
`LSSCM[client_age >=31 & client_age <=39, agegroup := "31-39"]`
`LSSCM[client_age >=40 & client_age <=54, agegroup := "40-54"]`
`LSSCM[client_age >=55 & client_age <=64, agegroup := "55-64"]`
`LSSCM[client_age >=65 & client_age <=75, agegroup := "65-75"]`
`LSSCM[client_age >=76, agegroup := "76+"]`
```

## Also tried.

```
LSSCM$age_cat <- case_when(LSSCM$client_age <= 17 ~ '0-17',
                           between(LSSCM$client_age, 18, 24) ~ '18-24',`
                           between(LSSCM$client_age, 25, 30) ~ '25-30',`
                           between(LSSCM$client_age, 31, 39) ~ '31-39',`
                           between(LSSCM$client_age, 40, 54) ~ '40-54',`
                           between(LSSCM$client_age, 55, 64) ~ '55-64',`
                           between(LSSCM$client_age, 65, 75) ~ '65-75',`
                           LSSCM$client_age >= 76 ~ '76+')`
```

Comment: After you try the one with `case_when`, what happens? How do you know it didn't work?

Comment: The recoding worked, but when i opened the dataset (frame, whatever), i couldn't find it.  There are only 32 variables, so it's not like it was hard to see.  It just wasn't there.  I scrolled back and forth a ton.  But i could run a freq on it.  So it was somewhere.

Comment: Ok, i ended up getting frustrated and deleted everything and started over and now it's coming up.  ???  I did literally nothing different.  I swear. I re-ran the setDT one when i started over and it IS showing up in the data.frame now.  Thanks.  I swear, i breathe on this stuff wrong and stuff goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply assign the result of your preferred solution into a column in the data.frame. For example:

```
df$agegroups<-cut(df$ages, breaks=c(20, 30, 40, 50), right = FALSE)
```

For example:

```
df<-data.frame(age = c(55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95))
df
  age
1  55
2  60
3  65
4  70
5  75
6  80
7  85
8  90
9  95
df$age_cat<-cut(df$age, breaks=c(0,17,24,30,39,54,64,75), right = FALSE)
df
  age age_cat
1  55 [54,64)
2  60 [54,64)
3  65 [64,75)
4  70 [64,75)
5  75    <NA>
6  80    <NA>
7  85    <NA>
8  90    <NA>
9  95    <NA>
```

Comment: I tried that with one of them and it still didn't show up:<br/>












`LSSCM$age_cat <- case_when(LSSCM$client_age <= 17 ~ '0-17'`

Comment: Still didn't work:</br>

`LSSCM$age_cat<-cut(LSSCM$client_age, breaks=c(0,17,24,30,39,54,64,75), right = FALSE)
`

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on without sample data for reproducing it...

Comment: Can you provide in your original question some sample data using `dput(head(LSSCM))`?

Comment: I apparently suck at formatting, so any help on making the code parts look right, would be greatly appreciated.  I'm using the tilde, but apparently to hit or miss effect.

Comment: To format code just append four spaces before each line. No tidles or approstrophes needed

Comment: But what I'm missing is some actual data, so I can see what's going on, because what you tried should work.